# Oracle Linux 7: Autostart Oracle with init.d

Tags: init.d, oracle-linux, oracle-database

I try to make Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 start with the system via init.d on my Oracle Linux 7.3 machine.

I followed this example: https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/automating-database-startup-and-shutdown-on-linux

This is my script to start the db:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 345 99 10
# description: Oracle auto start-stop script.
#
# Set ORA_HOME to be equivalent to the $ORACLE_HOME
# from which you wish to execute dbstart and dbshut;
#
# Set ORA_OWNER to the user id of the owner of the 
# Oracle database in ORA_HOME.

ORA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1
ORA_OWNER=oracle

case "$1" in
    'start')
        # Start the Oracle databases:
        # The following command assumes that the oracle login 
        # will not prompt the user for any values
        # Remove "&" if you don't want startup as a background process.
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start" &
        su $ORA_OWNER -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart &
        touch /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
    'stop')
        # Stop the Oracle databases:
        # The following command assumes that the oracle login 
        # will not prompt the user for any values
        su $ORA_OWNER -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
esac
```

Nothing happens upon start. I created soft links in `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc3.d`:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/dbora /etc/rc0.d/K10dbora
ln -s /etc/init.d/dbora /etc/rc3.d/S99dbora
chkconfig --level 2345 dbora on
```

`chkconfig` lists the `dbora.sh` with `runlevel 2345` on

manually starting with a short script works just fine, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe that Oracle Linux 7 does not use the traditional init, but has switched to systemd for controlling the system including stopping and starting services. You'll need to create a "unit configuration file" to stop and start Oracle. I'm sure there are examples floating around on the net.

Comment: If you found a solution, followup with an answer so that others searching for this can find a solution. You're allowed to answer your own question as long as you give enough info, e.g. include the unit file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to wurtel, I found the solution. To get the Oracle DB running with the machine, I had to use systemd. Here's a Guide to it:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/automating-database-startup-and-shutdown-on-linux#oracle-11gr2-update

Follow the Oracle 11gR2+ Section (the last one) on how to create a startup.sh and a shutdown.sh. Then follow this tutorial, to setup the unit file:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-services-systemd#creating-linux-services

Works like a charm :)